# Can I / Should I compile with SDK 23 if my max SDK is 20?

Tags: android

My project is aimed at IceCreamSandwich, JellyBean, KitKat and Lollipop.
Should I / Can I compile using SDK 23 or should I use SDK 20 as it has been until now?

Comment: why are you even setting the max sdk? using that is strongly discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use latest API, as long as you have support library v7 included in your project.

Comment: So I can keep having api 20 as my max sdk but compile with 23, right? And you are saying I can, but should I? Is there a reason to compile with a higher version?

Comment: Yes indeed. Basically it's advised to used latest API by Google, as then you will get all the latest bug fixes in your project.